# Using a method for WebOperationContext of WCF endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there any way I can avoid having this in all my endpoints? I'd like to put it in a method if possible.

```
IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;
var token = headers["Token"];
```

I can't use a message inspector behavior for the service because I have to do stuff with the token content inside the endpoint.

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/data/{id}",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Data GetData(string id)
        {
            IncomingWebRequestContext request = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
            WebHeaderCollection headers = request.Headers;
            var tokenHeader = headers["Token"];
            // need stuff from decoded token here so I can't just use a message inspector in endpoint dispatch
    }
```

Comment: So you handle the token with different behaviour based on the request handler?

Comment: it doesn't matter how I handle the request in the message inspector, i need to use data in the endpoint code so having different behaviour won't solve the problem